# Need Name of Children's Short Story (1970s SRA, maybe) - Boy Fixes Radio of a Crashed Alien Craft

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, childrens-novel, communication, ufos

I'm interested in the title and/or author of this story. I was in grade school from 1971 to 1978. The story collections we read were SRA (reading laboratories). Usually boring stuff. But I found back then in one of the readers a short story about a boy who finds an electronic component lying on the ground, and he brings it home and hooks it up to a radio, and that enables him to communicate with a being from another planet. This communication enables that alien-being to save his fellow being who crashed his ship (saucer maybe) on Earth.  I'm not positive it was part of the SRA collection.

Comment: I remember this, but i don't have the answer.  You gave me a clue to my story-identification question.  I forgot the name of the SRA (reading Laboratories) educational sets.  Thank you!!

Comment: I have three of the books (H-J) and it's not in them. I have just bought another two (G and L) because I'm trying to complete the whole set (SRA 1971). If I find it in G or L I will let you know.

Comment: Same story as in [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80415/short-story-about-a-boy-talking-to-an-alien-on-his-computer-alien-asking-for-he) maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be "[The Gizmo From Outer Space](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1564027.The_Gismo_from_Outer_Space)" by Keo Felker Lazarus

[image: Cover]

> The gismo that Jerry and Ron have found is no ordinary gadget. It's part of an alien spaceship's radio...and what's more, they must return it. But how?
>
> How do you keep a date with a man from outer space? And when your father asks where you think you're going at 12 midnight, how do you explain?

Comment: Nice! Could you include some of those details in your answer? That will make it more useful, particularly if the link goes dead.